# Assign formula to Name relating to certain cell (Name Manager)

Tags: excel, vba, namespaces

I try to assign the formula to name like this (image) via VBA:
[image: link to image]

I know how to do it manually, but how it can be achieved by macro?

The formula is related to the cell (not all links there are locked, and when you do it by your hands, you have to keep your eye on selected cell), that is a most complex thing for projecting this on VBA.

Have this code, helped me to start:

```
Sub auto()
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SF_{} {RU04}").Cells(204, 15).Select
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Sometotal", _
RefersTo:="=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(H168,GIT!$M$93:$N$126,2,0),0)"
End Sub
```

**Edit:** I solved my issue with guidance in accepted answer and comments to it.

Comment: Looks like by default, using code above it adds formula, like excel "thinking" that formula is for A1 cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following :

```
Sub NameRange_Add()    
    Dim RangeName As String        
    RangeName = "Sometotal"
    
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=RangeName, RefersToR1C1:="=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R168C8,GIT!R93C13:R126C14,2,0),0)"    
End Sub
```

Comment: Great solution, thank you, sir! Can I avoid locking a number of row after H in the formula 
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP('SF_{} {RU04}'!$H$204,GIT!$M$93:$N$126,2,0),0)
in this line of code?
RefersToR1C1:="=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R204C8,GIT!R93C13:R126C14,2,0),0)"

Comment: Good too, but how can I make row after H in formula to be not locked?
[link to image](https://imgur.com/43N0WTK)

Comment: I'll show you the picture [link](https://imgur.com/fDq8QX3). Thank you anyway

Comment: https://bettersolutions.com/excel/formulas/cell-references-a1-r1c1-notation.htm

Comment: Great, thank you very much. For anyone who comes up to this question, I added square brackets to number of row.